# C# TCP Client using high CPU when launched with Process.Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP Net Core 3.1 web app which launches a console app on startup...

```
Process p = new Process ();
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine ( env.ContentRootPath , "MyProcess" , "myprocess.exe" );
p.Start ();
```

The process launched listens for TCP connections like this:

```
while ( true )
{
     if ( theTcpListenerServer.Pending() )
     {
         Task.Run(() =>
         {
            using ( TcpClient client = theTcpListenerServer.AcceptTcpClient() )
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] aByteArray = new byte[ client.SendBufferSize ];

                    theStream = client.GetStream()
                    int aRecv;

                    while ( true )
                    {
                        aRecv = theStream.Read(aByteArray , 0 , client.SendBufferSize);
                        aData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aByteArray , 0 , aRecv);

                        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(aData) )
                        {
                            RaisePackageReceivedEvent(aData);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    //log some info
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

This process runs on pretty much 0% CPU if I launch it standalone, but launching it from the web app makes it use like 30% CPU. Originally the code did not have the Task.Run bit and I also added the Thread.Sleep(10). I tried redirecting output as well when I call Process.Start, but nothing helped.

Comment: i am not an expert on this stuff, but while(true) is an enemy of the cpu.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy That's where the Thread.Sleep(10) is supposed to help as I read in other answers. But that would not explain the difference in launching it from the exe or with Process.Start() right?

Comment: At what point do you await the Task

Comment: @Charlieface I don't, but actually it is never reaching that point, since this is happening when no connections are being made (i.e., Pending() is always false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling my hair a lot, the error was in another part of the code (in the web app). I was doing the following:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port)){
    JObject jsonObj = myObj.ToJSON(); // can return null if error
    if(jsonObj == null) return false;

    // rest of operations
}
```

For some reason, opening the TCP client and not doing anything was failing (probably it hanged inside the second while(true), but I'm not sure).

After moving the code so it looks like this...

```
JObject jsonObj = myObj.ToJSON(); // can return null if error
if(jsonObj == null) return false;

using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port)){
    // rest of operations
}
```

It works perfectly with the objects that are supposed to work, and does not open empty TCP Clients when the JSONs are null.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to call `theTcpListenerServer.AcceptTcpClient()` before you spawn off the task. Then process the received client in the task. No need to call `theTcpListenerServer.Pending()`, that will waste cpu cycles. `AcceptTcpClient` will do the right thing and use minimal CPU while blocking and waiting for a connection.

Either way, this seems like something you could just spawn in a task directly in your web app. No need for another process.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually added the Pending, but it was written like you say before (and did not work). However, the problem was finally in another place (I will add an answer later). I must do it in another process since this uses some Windows native code that I cannot control and I must maintain the general app cross-platform.